# Clarify the "self-learner" badge description

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, answers, self-answer

The "self-learner" badge description states "Answered your own question with score of 3 or more", but does that mean the **question** should have a score of 3 or more, or is it the **answer** that should have 3 or more?

If it's the answer, perhaps the description should make it clearer. For example:

> Answered your own question, and got a score of 3 or more on the answer

Comment: @MartijnPieters, why mark the older question as a duplicate of the newer one? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: No, duplicate question closing is not required to go from newer to older. The other question is worded better (it doesn't have a grammar mistake, for example) and has been received better.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, this question also has more answers and more discussions in the comments. I guess it could have been improved if there as a grammatical mistake but closing it wasn't necessary. Also I now I can think of another description that needs to be fixed: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." to "This question has been asked before **or after** and already has an answer."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at [the list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) for this badge:

> #### Self-Learner
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Provide an answer to your own question that receives a score of three

Now I'm fairly confident that it's the **answer** that has to reach a score of 3 or more, and that the the question's score isn't relevant.

But I (and the commenters below) agree with you that the badge description is somewhat ambiguous, as is the the "full" description in the post linked.

Comment: This was my gut instinct, and I pulled up the exact same FAQ to see what the description was there. But I honestly think that description could be slightly ambiguous as well. It depends entirely on which phrases you see as subordinate: "Provide an answer (to your own question) that receives a score of three", with score modifying answer, or "Provide an answer to your own question that receives a score of three", with score modifying question.

Comment: How do we know that `that` means answer and not question? Ask at English.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Hmmm true, it's still not the clearest of sentences. Still, I've had the badge before and I'm pretty sure it happens when the answer hits the three vote mark.

Comment: It's definitely about the answer.  I read this question more as a concern about the ambiguous wording, though.

Comment: I think the description should be more explicit. Something like "Answered your own question, and got a score of 3 or more on the answer".

Comment: Ah yes @Cody, it's been swapped to a [tag:feature-request] now, I'd missed that. I'll amend my answer a little.

Answer (score 5):

Since it's about self learning, you get the badge if your answer receives a score of 3.

If we rearrange the words the description is more clear,

> Provide an answer that receives a score of three to your own question